# Multiplication of two columns by data in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have been recently trying to develop a code for the multiplication of two column data in `JTable` by clicking a button. The code inside button click action is as follows:

```
for (int i=0;i<model.getRowCount();i++){
     Double d= Double.parseDouble((String) model2.getValueAt(i,1));
     Double d2= Double.parseDouble((String) model3.getValueAt(i,2));
     Double d3=d*d2;
     model.setValueAt(d3,i,3);
}
```

The generate button adds the number of rows from the spinner box based on the N value:

[image]

The button performs the above code. While running the application, I am getting the following errors and warnings:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1838)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at mU$4.actionPerformed(mU.java:133)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Can anyone please correct my code or tell me the logic how to multiply the data in `JTable` by column data?

The full code is as follows

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class mU extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;
    private JTextField textField;
    Double l2;
    Double l4;
    Double d,d2;
    int hu;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mU frame = new mU();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public mU() {
        try{    
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
        }
        catch(Exception w1){

        }  

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 486, 297);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblNumberOfMachines = new JLabel("Number of Machines");
        lblNumberOfMachines.setBounds(10, 11, 120, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblNumberOfMachines);

        JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
        spinner.setBounds(140, 8, 48, 20);
        contentPane.add(spinner);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(208, 11, 252, 239);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);

        table = new JTable();
        table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
            },
            new String[] {
                "Machine", "N(1)", "N(0)", "Qan"
            }
        ));
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        table.setModel(model);

        JLabel lblSum = new JLabel("Sum");
        lblSum.setBounds(10, 117, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblSum);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(39, 114, 105, 20);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Generate");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                table.setModel(model);
                int hu=(Integer) spinner.getValue();
                for(int i=0;i<hu;i++) {
                    model.addRow(new Object[] {"M"+(i+1),null,null,null});

                }
            }
        });

        btnNewButton.setBounds(10, 36, 77, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);


        JButton btnClear = new JButton("CLEAR");
        btnClear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                model.setRowCount(0);
            }
        });
        btnClear.setBounds(89, 36, 65, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnClear);

        JButton btnInitilize = new JButton("N");
        btnInitilize.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                for (int i = 0; i <model.getRowCount(); i++) {
                     Double d= Double.parseDouble((String) model.getValueAt(i,1));
                     Double d2= Double.parseDouble((String) model.getValueAt(i,2));
                    Double d3=d*d2;
                    model.setValueAt(d3,i,3);
                 }  

            }
        });
        btnInitilize.setBounds(10, 63, 46, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnInitilize);










    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ActionListener` for your <kbd>Generate</kbd> button repeatedly adds `null` to the `TableModel`, which causes [`Double.parseDouble()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble-java.lang.String-) to throw `NullPointerException`. At a minimum, add parseable values to your model:

```
for (int i = 0; i < hu; i++) {
    String s = String.valueOf(i);
    model.addRow(new Object[] {"M" + s, s, "42", ""});
}
```

[image]

> Can you put down me the correct code please?

The chosen values are for illustration; you'll likely want to start with the string representation of the identity element, e.g. `"0"`:

```
model.addRow(new Object[] {"M" + s, "0", "0", ""});
```

As an aside, the screenshot illustrates why you should avoid absolute positioning in favor of a suitable [layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: Well thanks for the answer, but the problem by the number of input in spinner box the table should add those rows and user then fills the table by values. And then user presses the N button where it would take the values in 1 column and 2 column and then multiply them and should fill those values in third column can you help on this

Comment: Thank you very much for reply, as I am not an avid programmer and out of enthusiasm i have started to learn java swings, if you have no problem can you put down me the correct code please , thank you

Comment: Certainly; I've elaborated above.

Comment: Ok, can you help me out with one last favour how to make row headers in above table I have seen many tutorials and forums but I am unable to catch them out can you put me the code snippet please

Comment: hi, i have tried it but multiplication of last columns is not showing and leaving me an error like index_out_of_bonds and so much more

Comment: @NagaSairam: Sounds like it needs some debugging; if you ask a new question, be sure to include your current [mcve] and cite any relevant [example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20%5bjtable%5d%20getvalueat%20total).

Comment: How to do that citing and tell status of problem

Comment: In you new question, add a link to this question; mention what particular aspect of your program you're trying to improve; show what you've tried and where you got stuck; see [ask] for details.

Comment: I have tried all the steps but failing so badly can anyone please help me out with this problem

Comment: Nothing new I just made the correction what you have suggested and I am getting the all the values except I am unable to get the last row results if you want to put me the code I can do it

Comment: Oh, I though you were doing something else; try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45630560/230513)